# H2 (File) Delete Performance

Tags: java, database, h2

I've encountered somewhat problematic performance issues when it comes to a file-based H2 database in AUTO-SERVER mode. I am using H2 version 1.3.174. The database contains a single table with 5 columns. One of the columns is a CLOB, that (on average) contains 1 KB of text data per row. In a single-threaded test run, I've inserted 800,000 rows, which took 409 seconds - OK for me. I've executed a second test run with the following steps:

1. Load the first 100 messages from the database. Order of messages is established via primary key (NUMBER) value.
2. Delete those 100 messages with the following statement: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (...);

This is done until 790,000 rows of the database are deleted. In my real-world scenario, there would be some processing involved between steps 1 and 2. This second test run took 8.5 hours, on a fast machine under no load! I've observed that during the deletion, H2 created temporary files with names like "mydb.1978734278.38.temp.db", whose size varies fast between 24 and 1,300 MB.

Is this expected behavior? Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you index your `id` column?

Comment: Hi andyf - yes, the ID column is the primary key column and has a "PRIMARY KEY" index.

Comment: The problem may be that you are using CLOB, that will create temp files(which slow down performance)

Comment: Ref here: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#large_objects

Comment: Hm,I don't think I'll get around CLOBs in my case. I could try to store the data in a large VARCHAR column and see if that makes any difference. I find it strange that I don't see any temp files after the first test run though, only when the deletes occur. Shouldn't there be temp files when storing CLOBs?

Comment: Having identified the use of CLOB as a potential problem, I've changed the table structure to use a VARCHAR(4096) column instead. Results: INSERT speed increases about 25%, File size is cut in half: 1.6 GB instead of 3.2 GB! Unfortunately, DELETEs again seem to take ages, the test is executing right now. Also: the .temp.db files are there again as soon as the DELETEs start, so I don't think they have anything to do with CLOB. Any other ideas? I like the INSERT performance, but I really need efficient batch DELETE behavior in my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question with my findings:

1. The main problem were the SELECT statements, this was due to a missing index. Once the proper INDEX was in place the SELECT/DELETE test run only took 2 minutes.
2. There seems to be a space problem when using CLOBS or LONGVARBINARY instead of VARCHAR: the file size was cut in half when using the latter.